# Title goes below cursor on Windows, Chrome in case of a too big cursor

Tags: html, google-chrome, pointers, window, cursor

Here is my code:

```
<div title="foo">
some text
</div>


div {
  cursor: default;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/am4zsh8e/2/

If I go to `Mouse pointer` setting in Windows and change the `Change pointer size` to something big and then hover over the `some text` the `foo` will be drawn below the cursor. I can not make a screenshot of it (the screenshot depicts a small pointer).

Is it possible to fix somehow? I.e. make the title get drawn below the cursor, not underneath it.

[image]

I enlarged the pointer on screenshot manually to demonstrate the issue, since when I do a screenshot the pointer does not get recorded for some reasons.

Is it maybe possible to tell Chrome to always draw the title above the cursor (i.e. above along the screen height and not the screen depth; controlling the screen depth would be nice as well though, but not exactly what I would like in this case)?